Source of the Chitta's impressions and experiences
From where does the Chitta acquire impressions and experiences? Directly from Manas or from Manas to Buddhi and Buddhi to Chitta?

Sankhya-karika XXIII explains that ascertainment is one of the functions of the intellect, or buddhi. Edwin Bryant lists all the functions of buddhi as follows: "Intelligence is characterized by the functions of judgment, discrimination, knowledge, ascertainment, will, virtue, and detachment." (from the introductory essay The Sankhya Metaphysics of the Text, in Bryant's edition of the Yoga sutras) Bryant defines the functions of the mind as follows: "The mind is the seat of the emotions, of like and dislike, and filters and processes the potentially enormous amount of data accessible to the senses. It primarily receives, sorts, categorizes and then transmits. It serves as the liaison between the activities of the senses transmitting data from the external world, and buddhi, intelligence."
Bryant then quotes the famous analogy of the chariot driven by five horses (the senses) from the Katha Upanishad (3.9).
From this description, we can understand that sensory experience first passes through the filter of the mind, and then through the filter of the intelligence, before influencing the citta by reinforcing, overwriting, or otherwise altering existing samskaras. Graphically, it's like this = viṣayas (sense objects) ==> indriyas (senses) ==> mind (manas) ==> intellect (buddhi) ==> materially contaminated consciousness (citta, also known as the antaḥ-kāraṇa).
To understand the role the buddhi plays in the formation or alteration of samskaras in the citta, we can consider its function of judgment. Take the example of something like meat. When a person who judges meat as good comes in contact with it, this reinforces his samskaras of attachment to meat. When a person who judges meat as bad comes in contact with it, this reinforces his samskaras of detachment. In both cases, the experience is the same on the level of the visaya (meat), the sensory experience, and the raw mental input, but the key difference is found in the intellectual disposition.
Of course, there will also be differing emotional responses in the mind, which further influence the quality of the samskaras formed in any given experience. But these emotional experiences are themselves supported by and informed by the intellect (buddhi).
Another illustration is found in a person who is in a perfect state of waking samadhi. Although he interacts with the world and externally perceives so many sense objects, he remains unaffected. This is due to his enlightened intellect. He perfectly sees all material experience as devoid of inherent value, and so develops no emotional response, nor any sense of attachment or aversion, etc. By dint of his enlightened intellect, his mind remains absorbed in the ātmā at all times.
I suggest reading Edwin Bryant's text and commentary on the first ten or so of the Yoga Sutras for further discussion on this topic.
Namaste. Hare Rama 

Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, clear examples and the references. I have one more question. How does buddhi process a previously unexperienced sensory perception?
